# Is Cassandra broken or have I made a huge mistake?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, nosql

I have worked with Cassandra quite a bit and feel like I have already put up with enough BS from the database over the years. Just wondering why this isn't working in Apache Cassandra 2.1.0 (or 2.0.8) w/ 2.1.1 of the datastax java driver. It really seems like this should work.

```
public class BS {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
           Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("192.168.1.6").build();
           Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();
           System.out.printf("Connected to cluster: %s\n", metadata.getClusterName());
           Session session = cluster.connect();
           
           session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS fook WITH replication= {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1 }");
           session.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fook.dooftbl (id bigint PRIMARY KEY, doof text, ownerid bigint)");
                      
           long id = new Random().nextLong();
           long ownerid = new Random().nextLong();
           String doof = "broken db";
           
           String load = "INSERT INTO fook.dooftbl (id,doof,ownerid) VALUES (?,?,?)";
           PreparedStatement ps = session.prepare(load);
           session.execute(ps.bind(id,doof,ownerid));
           
                
        try {
            String cql = "SELECT doof FROM fook.dooftbl WHERE id=?";
            PreparedStatement ps2 = session.prepare(cql);
            ResultSet rs= session.execute(ps2.bind(id));
            System.out.println("Result set: " + rs.toString() + " size: " + rs.all().size() + " fullyFetched:" + rs.isFullyFetched());

            //Row one = rs.one();
            //if (one!=null)
            //  System.out.println("It worked. You will never have to worry about seeing this msg.");
            
            String msg = null;
            for (Row r : rs.all()) {
                msg = r.getString("doof");              
            }           
            System.out.println("msg:" + msg);

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                    
            }
        cluster.close();
    }
    
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is it something relatively minor?

> Outputs:
>
> Connected to cluster: Test Cluster
>
> Result set: ResultSet[ exhausted: false, Columns[doof(varchar)]] size: 1 fullyFetched:true
>
> msg:null

Comment: Please describe _isn't working_. What do you expect it to do and why? What does it do instead?

Comment: At a bare minimum I'd expect it to show the "It worked..." String. Instead, it doesn't show it.

Comment: @AlexWhite What _does_ it show? `Connected to cluster` at least?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're invoking

```
rs.all()
```

which, [as the javadoc says](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html#all%28%29),

> Returns all the remaining rows in this ResultSet as a list.
>
> Note that, contrary to `iterator()` or **successive calls to `one()`**, **this
>   method forces fetching the full content of the ResultSet at once**,
>   holding it all in memory in particular. It is thus recommended to
>   prefer iterations through `iterator()` when possible, especially if the
>   `ResultSet` can be big.

So, when you then do

```
Row one = rs.one();
```

which, [as the javadoc states](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html#one%28%29), returns

> the next row in this resultSet or `null` if this `ResultSet` is exhausted.

it will return `null` since the `ResultSet` is exhausted.

You would have seen

```
Result set: ResultSet[ exhausted: false, Columns[doof(varchar)]] size: 1 fullyFetched:true
```

in your logs which shows the row you added previously.

Comment: @AlexWhite Yes, if you invoke `ResultSet#isExhausted()` after the call to `ResultSet#all()`, it will return `true`. I don't know what you mean by _fails_. I remove the `all()` call and the `one()` call, and the `for` loop correctly prints `msg:broken db` after consuming the single row.

Comment: @AlexWhite No, I just downloaded Cassandra to try your example. You keep saying things don't work. Edit your question, post the new code you are trying to run and the _exact_ output. Then tell us what you were expecting.

Comment: @AlexWhite From your edit, you're still invoking `all()`, which consumes the full `ResultSet`, there's nothing left once you reach the `for` loop. Notice how `size` is 1.